# how can I count the strings and set a number?

Tags: r

I have a data looking like this

```
df <- structure(list(Mydf = c("TNFM00000001497", "TNFM00000001617", 
"TNFM00000001617", "TNFM00000001617", "TNFM00000001617", "TNFM00000001626", 
"TNFM00000001626", "TNFM00000001626", "TNFM00000001626", "TNFM00000001629", 
"TNFM00000001629", "TNFM00000001630", "TNFM00000001630", "TNFM00000001630"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

I want to count how many times a string is repeated and then give me an example output like this

```
String           Number of repeat
TNFM00000001497   1
TNFM00000001617   4
TNFM00000001626   4
TNFM00000001629   2
TNFM00000001630   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `table`

```
> table(df)
df
TNFM00000001497 TNFM00000001617 TNFM00000001626 TNFM00000001629 TNFM00000001630
              1               4               4               2               3
```

or

```
> as.data.frame(table(df))
               df Freq
1 TNFM00000001497    1
2 TNFM00000001617    4
3 TNFM00000001626    4
4 TNFM00000001629    2
5 TNFM00000001630    3
```

or

```
> stack(table(df))
  values             ind
1      1 TNFM00000001497
2      4 TNFM00000001617
3      4 TNFM00000001626
4      2 TNFM00000001629
5      3 TNFM00000001630
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be:

```
aggregate(df$Mydf, list(freq = df$Mydf), length)

# freq x
# 1 TNFM00000001497 1
# 2 TNFM00000001617 4
# 3 TNFM00000001626 4
# 4 TNFM00000001629 2
# 5 TNFM00000001630 3
```

`tapply` can work here as well:

```
tapply(df$Mydf, df$Mydf, length)
```

Comment: very useful command , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `group_by` and `count`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(String = Mydf) %>% 
  count()

# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   String [5]
  String              n
  <chr>           <int>
1 TNFM00000001497     1
2 TNFM00000001617     4
3 TNFM00000001626     4
4 TNFM00000001629     2
5 TNFM00000001630     3
```

Comment: thanks, nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% add_count(Mydf) %>% distinct

#>              Mydf n
#> 1 TNFM00000001497 1
#> 2 TNFM00000001617 4
#> 3 TNFM00000001626 4
#> 4 TNFM00000001629 2
#> 5 TNFM00000001630 3
```